# Adding a validation dynamically to a multifield in a CQ5 dialog based on user selection

Tags: javascript, extjs, aem

I need to make the title of a multifield as mandatory based on the value of my selection field. This is what my multifield looks like

```
var foo = {};

foo.testWidget = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.form.CompositeField, {

/**
 * @private
 * @type CQ.Ext.form.Hidden
 */
hiddenField : null,

titleField:null,
subTitleField:null,
description:null,
elementImage:null,
linkText:null,
linkURL:null,
anchorField:null,
emptyField:null,


constructor : function(config) {
    config = config || {};
    var defaults = {
        "border" : true
    };
    config = CQ.Util.applyDefaults(config, defaults);
    foo.testWidget.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
},

// overriding CQ.Ext.Component#initComponent
initComponent : function() {
    foo.testWidget.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

    this.hiddenField = new CQ.Ext.form.Hidden({
        name : this.name
    });
    this.add(this.hiddenField);


    this.titleField = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
        fieldLabel : "Title",
        labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
        maxLength : "50",
        cls : "potato",
        width : 400,
        allowBlank : true,
        listeners : {
            change : {
                scope : this,
                fn : this.updateHidden
            }
        }
    });
    this.add(this.titleField);

    this.subTitleField = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
        fieldLabel : "Subtitle",
        labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
        maxLength : "150",
        width : 400,
        allowBlank : true,
        listeners : {
            change : {
                scope : this,
                fn : this.updateHidden
            }
        }
    });
    this.add(this.subTitleField);

    this.description = new CQ.Ext.form.TextArea({
        fieldLabel : "Description",
        labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
        maxLength : "200",
        width : 400,
        allowBlank : true,
        listeners : {
            change : {
                scope : this,
                fn : this.updateHidden
            }
        }
    });
    this.add(this.description);

    this.elementImage = new CQ.form.PathField({
        fieldLabel : "Banner Image",
        fieldDescription : "Specify image path",
        labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
        rootPath : "/content/dam/foo",
        editable : false,
        width : 400,
        allowBlank : true,
        listeners : {
            dialogselect : {
                scope : this,
                fn : this.updateHidden
            },
            change : {
                scope : this,
                fn : this.updateHidden
            }
        }
    });
    this.add(this.elementImage);

    this.linkText = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
        fieldLabel : "Enter Link Text",
        labelStyle : 'display:block;width:92px;',
        maxLength : "40",
        width : 400,
        allowBlank : false,
        listeners : {
            change : {
                scope : this,
                fn : this.updateHidden
            }
        }
    });
    this.add(this.linkText);

    this.linkURL = new CQ.form.PathField({
        fieldLabel : "Complete URL for the element CTA",
        labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
        rootPath : "/content/foo",
        editable : true,
        width : 400,
        allowBlank : false,
        listeners : {
            dialogselect : {
                scope : this,
                fn : this.updateHidden
            },
            change : {
                scope : this,
                fn : this.updateHidden
            }
        }
    });
    this.add(this.linkURL);

     this.anchorField =  new CQ.form.Selection({
        type:"checkbox",
        fieldLabel:"Link Target",
        fieldDescription:"Select the browser tab in which the link should be opened",
        options:displayOptionsTarget(),
        listeners: {
            selectionchanged: {
                scope:this,
                fn: this.updateHidden
            }
        },
        optionsProvider: this.optionsProvider
    });
    this.add(this.anchorField);


    /**
     * Added a dummy Empty field to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception in the resultant array
     * Without this hidden field, the empty values will be not be added to the multifield list
     */
    this.emptyField = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
        fieldLabel: "Empty Field",
        width:200,
        maxLength: "30",
        defaultValue: "empty",
        hidden:true,
        value:"empty",
    });
    this.add(this.emptyField);

},

// overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#setValue
setValue : function(value) {

    var parts = value.split(/<#-@>/);
    console.log("Related Resources Slider #parts", parts);
    this.titleField.setValue(parts[0]);
    this.subTitleField.setValue(parts[1]);
    this.description.setValue(parts[2]);
    this.elementImage.setValue(parts[3]);
    this.linkText.setValue(parts[4]);
    this.linkURL.setValue(parts[5]);
    this.anchorField.setValue(parts[6]);
    this.emptyField.setValue(parts[7]);


    this.hiddenField.setRawValue(value);

},

// overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#getValue
getValue : function() {
    return this.getRawValue();
},

// overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#getRawValue
getRawValue : function() {
    return this.titleField.getValue() + "<#-@>"
            + this.subTitleField.getValue() + "<#-@>"
            + this.description.getValue() + "<#-@>"
            + this.elementImage.getValue() + "<#-@>"
            + this.linkText.getValue() + "<#-@>"
            + this.linkURL.getValue() + "<#-@>"
            + this.anchorField.getValue() + "<#-@>"
            + this.emptyField.getValue()
},

// private
updateHidden : function() {
    this.hiddenField.setValue(this.getValue());
}

});

function displayOptionsTarget()
{
return [{
    "text":"check to open link in new tab",
    "value":true

}]
}


// register xtype
foo.testWidget.XTYPE = "testXtype";
CQ.Ext.reg(foo.testWidget.XTYPE, foo.testWidget);
```

I added a listener to my dialog, which executes the following JavaScript code `beforesubmit`

```
function(){
var dialog = this.findParentByType('dialog');
var selection = this.findByType('selection');
var choice = selection[0].getValue();
var multi = this.findByType('customMultifield')[0];
var textfield = multi.findByType('textfield')[0];

if(choice=2){

    textfield. markInvalid("mandatory for current choice");
    return false;
}
}
```

Although it is somewhat effective, what happens is that if I add 2 sets of multifield entries, with the first having a title and the second set of entries not having a title, it marks the titleField for the first set as invalid.

How can I set the correct textfield (titleField in each multifield entry) as invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wouldn't work because you are always checking the value of the first textfield and marking it invalid. Instead, you would have to loop through all the text fields, check the ones that are required and mark them invalid appropriately. The listener should look something like this.

```
function(dlg){
    var choice = dlg.getField('./choice').getValue();
    var submit = true;
    var multi = dlg.findByType('multifield')[0];
    if(choice == 2) {
    var textfields = multi.findByType('textfield');
    for(var i=0; i < textfields.length; i++) {
        if(textfields[i].fieldLabel == 'Title') {
        if(textfields[i].getValue().trim() == '') {
                    textfields[i]. markInvalid("mandatory for current choice");
            submit = false;
                }
        }
    }
    }
    return submit;
}
```

NOTE: Since your question doesn't have the structure of the dialog, I have assumed that there is a selection named `./choice`, whose value determines the status of the text fields.